# tensorflow prevent variables to be added to trainable variables

Tags: tensorflow

i'm using tensorflow while_loop. The problem is variables that i created in the body of the while_loop will be added to trainable variable. For example:

```
def body(b, c):
    a = b + c
    ...
    (others calculations that create variables like a)
    ...
    return b, c
```

a was add to trainable_variables

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) to obtain variables, then you could supply `trainable=False` to `tf.Variable`'s constructor. In your example, however, `a` is likely not a TensorFlow Variable ... (if `b` and `c` are Variable objects, then `a` is a Tensor). Without more context or code, there's not much else I can say.