# How does Tensorflow know which trainable variables need to be minimised?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to understand the `GradientDescentOptimizer` API in isolation and have created a minimal example to figure out what is going on:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Guess 2.5 as a starting point
x = tf.Variable(2.5, name='x', dtype=tf.float32)
log_x_squared = tf.square(tf.log(x))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)
train = optimizer.minimize(log_x_squared)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(init)
    print("start ", "x:", session.run(x), "log(x)^2:", session.run(log_x_squared))
    for step in range(10):  
      session.run(train)
      print("step", step, "x:", session.run(x), "log(x)^2:", session.run(log_x_squared))
```

Which outputs ...

```py
start  x: 2.5 log(x)^2: 0.83958876
step 0 x: 2.1334836 log(x)^2: 0.57419443
step 1 x: 1.7783105 log(x)^2: 0.33138883
step 2 x: 1.4545966 log(x)^2: 0.14042155
step 3 x: 1.1969798 log(x)^2: 0.032328587
step 4 x: 1.0467671 log(x)^2: 0.002089082
step 5 x: 1.0031027 log(x)^2: 9.596717e-06
step 6 x: 1.0000144 log(x)^2: 2.0805813e-10
step 7 x: 1.0 log(x)^2: 0.0
step 8 x: 1.0 log(x)^2: 0.0
step 9 x: 1.0 log(x)^2: 0.0
```

The minimize method is described in the API docs as:

> Add operations to minimize loss by updating `var_list`.
>
> This method simply combines calls compute_gradients() and
>   `apply_gradients()`. If you want to process the gradient before applying
>   them call `compute_gradients()` and `apply_gradients()` explicitly instead
>   of using this function.
>
> **Args:**
>
> ```
> loss: A Tensor containing the value to minimize.
> global_step: Optional Variable to increment by one after the variables have 
>              been updated.
> var_list: Optional list or tuple of Variable objects to update to minimize
>           loss.  Defaults to the list of variables collected in the
>           graph under the key GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES.
> ```

If I add some code to output the TRAINABLE_VARIABLES:

```py
for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES):
    print(v)
```

I see:

```py
<tf.Variable 'x:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
```

If I add another Variable to my code, it also gets output as a trainable variable, but only the x variable seems to be used by my `minimize()` method.  I have seen on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47277968/tensorflow-prevent-variables-to-be-added-to-trainable-variables) that it is possible to pass 'trainable=false' to variable declarations, but that doesn't seem to be needed.

Does Tensorflow inspect the minimize operation to identify which trainable variables are part of the function and then only update those variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Tensorflow inspect the minimize operation to identify which trainable variables are part of the function and then only update those variables?

In short, yes. When you're executing your `session.run(train)`, this is calling the `optimizer.minimize` function on `log_x_squared`. If you were to define another variable that had no reference to the rest of the graph, it would not be incorporated as it is not referenced at any other part.

[diagram of graph visibility when session.run(train) is executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly8BQ.png)